# Explicit vs implicit universes in lean

Tags: lean, lean-mathlib, lean3, universe

I've seen in mathlib several cases where the universes are explicit, that is `Type u` instead of `Type*`. Is there any advantage in doing so and are there any (non-category theory) examples where universes have to be named explicitly in lean even though the mathematics does not run into universe issues?

Comment: Are you referring to `Type*` vs `Type u` or `foo X` vs `foo.{u} X`?

Comment: Besides category theory, explicit universes are also used in `set_theory/`: cardinals, ordinals, a model of ZFC, surreal numbers, and game theory. All of these areas explicitly deal with size issues though (game theory is an outlier, but see the [hypergame paradox](https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2021/12/10/the-hypergame-paradox/) to get a sense of why universes can get involved).

Comment: the former, I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Type*` is just a shorthand for `Type _`, where the `_` is a wildcard (or more accurately, a universe metavariable) that lean will try to fill in for you. Lean's options are to:

- Create a new universe for you, which it will give a name like `u_1`.
- Reuse an existing universe variable.
- Use `max` and similar to combine universe levels.

Usually then, explicit universe variables are used either when control over the names is wanted, or when the automatic behavior does the wrong thing.

To demonstrate the automatic behavior a little:

- In a `variables` line, lean will almost always create new variables; so

  ```
  variables {α β : Type*}
  ```

  is expanded to

  ```
  universes u_1 u_2
  variables {α : Type u_1} {β : Type u_2}
  ```
- In something like

  ```
  example {α β : Type*} (h : α = β) : true := sorry
  ```

  Lean is forced during elaboration of `h` to put both in the same
  universe, so it generates

  ```
  universes u_1
  example {α β : Type u_1} (h : α = β) : true := sorry
  ```